# How to refactor a short circuit evaluation

Tags: delphi

I am from c++ background and I am confused with one of the statement like this

```
   if TUtils.CheckValue(objData, LChan) and
         (LChan.Int.Value = (aObject as TomDBChan).Int.Value) then
   begin
          //Operation
   end;
```

is it ok to convert this to

```
         LChan.Int.Value = (aObject as TomDBChan).Int.Value ;
          if TUtils.CheckValue(objData, LChan) then
          begin
            //Operation
          end;
```

or should i also check whether LChan.Int.Value has some value in it?

Comment: Your refactored code does not compile. What is your goal?

Comment: I also don't understand the C++ reference. Logical operators in C++ are also short circuit evaluated, from left to right.

Comment: My very best guess is that you are getting confused between C++ assignment and equality operators, = and == respectively. In Delphi the equivalents are := and =. Once you are clear as what the operators in use, and the fact that there is only comparison, and no assignment then you'll understand and know that you should not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to prevent any short-circuit evaluation, just make sure the constituent parts of the expression are calculated separately:

```
b1 := TUtils.CheckValue(objData, LChan);
b2 := (LChan.Int.Value = (aObject as TomDBChan).Int.Value);

if b1 and b2 then
begin
   //Operation
end;
```

This ensures that any side effects in CheckValue() or the .Value methods **will** be  executed.

Comment: I'm not sure what is gained from guessing at what the question is. Since the question currently makes no sense, I don't understand the point of this. Perhaps asker wants to avoid short circuit. Perhaps asker wants to break down a long expression without changing semantics. The latter would be a better fit with refactoring. But who knows?

Answer (score 1):

To make is clearer: your suggested refactor is not ok.

The statement: "LChan.Int.Value = (aObject as TomDBChan).Int.Value" returns either true or false and it would make no sense placing it outside the if condition.

You can not blindly refactor short circuit evaluation. That's because the right side is not evaluated if the left side is false. Your program logic changes by doing this.

I can not say what checkvalues does, but what if it checks for a null pointer? If you would refactor it to:

```
b1 := TUtils.CheckValue(objData, LChan);
b2 := (LChan.Int.Value = (aObject as TomDBChan).Int.Value);
```

And it turns out LChan would be null then your program would raise an exception on the b2 := ... because LChan.Int doesn't exist where it would previously not raise an exception.

LChan.Int.Value = (aObject as TomDBChan).Int.Value checks if they are equal, it doesn't assign (aObject as TomDBChan).Int.Value to LChan.Int.Value.